# C# using a static method and passing in database reader

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, npgsql

I am new to C# and have been hearing a lot about how dangerous static methods could be in a multi-threaded environment . I have a static method that I use throughout my application and takes in a Data Reader object . In a high concurrency environment would it be better to keep that method static or make a class and instantiate whenever I use it ? I am using .net core 3.1 and the method is **DBConnection.SafeRowCheck(Reader)**

*

```
  public static class DBConnection
     {
        public static string SafeRowCheck(NpgsqlDataReader Reader)
           {
                if (!Reader.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    return Reader.GetString(0);
                }
                return "";
        }
    }





    public async Task<string> View()
        {
          try
            {
                var results = string.Empty;
                using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(_appSettings.ConnectionString);
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                    using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("sql statement", conn);
                    await cmd.PrepareAsync();
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    using var Reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                    if (await Reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        results = DBConnection.SafeRowCheck(Reader);
                    }
                }
       Catch(Exception e)
         {
          // Catch exception
         }
      }
```

Comment: Static methods don't actually raise threading concerns. Static fields (and properties backed by them) raise threading concerns.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for clearing that up, so methods are ok and fields raise concerns .

Comment: A little unrelated but you can call `ExecuteScalarAsync()` to get the first value from the first row returned by the query instead of using a separate static method to read the reader, if you just want the one value like in your example.

Comment: @JacobHuckins thanks for the tip I will look into that one since i haven’t seen it before .